# Version of Canvas create_text() that supports word wrap?

Tags: python, user-interface, word-wrap, tkinter-canvas

Is there a `create_text()` mode or technique that supports word wrap? I'm stuck using `create_text()` vs. a `Label` or `Text` widget because I'm placing text on top of an image on my Canvas.

Also, is there a Tkinter API that truncates text that doesn't fit a certain width with an ellipsis like suffix, eg. `Where very, very, very long text` gets converted to something like `Where very, very, ...`.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

There is indeed a word wrap feature in `create_text()`. You'd call it like so:

```
canvas.create_text(x, y, width=80)
```

You can set the width parameter to whatever max length you want, or 0 if you want no word wrapping. See [this article](http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/canvas.htm#Tkinter.Canvas.create_text-method) for all the options, arguments etc. for `create_text()`.

I'm not sure about *truncating* text, but I did see [this](http://effbot.org/zone/tkinter-entry-validate.htm) talking about a way to limit the length of input in an Entry widget...

Comment: Thanks for your help. I'm embarrassed to say I totally missed the width= option for create_text(). Also thanks for the links. Note: Your 2nd link is bad - it should be: http://effbot.org/zone/tkinter-entry-validate.htm.

Comment: effbot is of course down for the time being, so the first link is more or less useless.